# cannot display Google Earth Engine Image in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook, google-earth-engine

I'm working on getting google earth engine working with my python setup (Windows 7, Python 2.7.8) using a tutorial I found online ([here](https://github.com/tylere/ee-jupyter-examples/blob/master/2%20-%20EE%20101.ipynb)). I can get EE to initialize, but cannot get it to display an image.

```
import ee
from IPython.display import Image,display
ee.Initialize()
image = ee.Image('srtm90_v4')
url = image.getThumbURL({'min':0,'max':3000})
Image(url)
```

The last line returns the following error:

> "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 Image(url)
>
> D:\miniconda\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\display.pyc in **init**(self, data, url, filename, format, embed, width, height, retina, unconfined, metadata)
>       750 
>       751         if self.embed and self.format not in self._ACCEPTABLE_EMBEDDINGS:
>   --> 752             raise ValueError("Cannot embed the '%s' image format" % (self.format))
>       753         self.width = width
>       754         self.height = height
>
> ValueError: Cannot embed the 'com/api/thumb?thumbid=a7f37aaf3e0e9a8ec6a0ef27f0a5ff89&token=34a700091c83cadbc034141f7ea765da' image format"

If I put the url into a web browser and save the image that comes up it saves a PNG. If I append PNG to the url, `Image(url+'.png')` `Image()` no longer throws an error and instead brings up:

```
 <IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

`display()` should be able to show this, but it also only brings up:

```
 <IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

If I point `Image()` to the saved PNG file it works fine:

```
Image('./test_thumb.png')
```

[SRTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jjdV.png)

Any ideas on what is causing `Image()` to not display the Google Earth Engine thumbnail?

I have tried added `%matplotlib lineline` after my initial imports (matplotlib is loaded via my ipython profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is using the wrong parameter of the `IPython.display.Image` constructor function. The `data` parameter is first, and the `url` argument is the second.

In Jupyter notebooks you can view the parameter lists for an object by using the help magic function (example: `help(Image)`) or by the `Shift-Tab` keyboard shortcut.

To resolve the issue, use the [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) form when calling the Image function:

```
Image(url=url)
```